# Advice not applied in unit tests

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-aop

Spring AOP advices are not being applied for unit tests. Everything seems to be working fine during normal execution and integration tests, but are not applied while running unit tests.

Relatively new to Spring and battling with this issue for a while. Looks like some configuration issue. Tried with different types of runners but did not have any luck. Also tried to integrate with AspectJWeaver for compile time weaving but hit many compile issues across the legacy code base which I stepped back.

**Unit test**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class UserServiceImpl

    private UserServiceImpl userServiceSpy; 
    @Mock
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Mock
    private MembershipDao membershipDao;
    @Mock
    private Service1 service1;
    @Mock
    private Service2 service2;
    @Mock
    private TroubleshootingLogService troubleshootingLogService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
       UserServiceImpl userService = new UserServiceImpl(userDao, membershipDao,service1, service2, <param1>, <param2>);

       userServiceSpy = spy(userService)
    // some other variables inits... 
    }

    // All the unit tests.
```

**Integration test**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestExecutionListeners(value = {FlywayTestExecutionListener.class}, mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@FlywayTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")

public class UserServiceIntegrationTest { 
    @ClassRule
    public static final WireMockClassRule wireMockRule = new WireMockClassRule(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort());

     @Autowire
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowire
    private MembershipDao membershipDao;
    @Autowire
    private Service1 service1;
    @Autowire
    private Service2 service2;

  @Before
  public void init(){
     //clean up persisted test states 

  }

  // All integration tests 

}
```

**Aspect**

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(1)
public class UserExceptionLoggingAdvisor extends AbstractExceptionLoggingAdvisor {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserExceptionLoggingAdvisor.class);

  @Around("@annotation(LogException) && args(directoryId, userId, userToUpdate)")
    public Object handleException(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String directoryId, String userId, ExternalUser userToUpdate) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.debug("Advising execution to handle possible ScimException");
}
```

When we have a breakpoint on the Aspect class, at `private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserExceptionLoggingAdvisor.class);` line, the unit test breaks. But it does not break at the actual @Around advice for unit tests while it does for integration tests.

Can anyone advise me on how to fix this issue.

Comment: "but fail while unit testing using mocks." You should precise which statement fails and with the error message associated if relevant to understand the context.

Comment: changed the description with better words :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to properly format (and at the same time syntax-highlight) code. I just did that for you. You can check it if you click "edit" on your question and see how I did it. Then just cancel the edit. :-)

Comment: Does your unit test really have the same class name `UserServiceImpl` as the subject under test or is it a typo and should be `UserServiceImplTest` or so? Furthermore, where is your actual `UserServiceImpl` class and where is the annotation definition? Please update the question and also add package names for all aspects and classes because Spring AOP pointcuts are kind of sensitive with regard to missing package names in pointcut definitions. The interface definition for `UserService` would also be helpful. Please learn what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "configuration issue"

Since you havn't disclosed how you are calling your unit tests and none of the classes. My guess is that it isn't triggered since you have expressed the fully qualified name to your `LogException` annotation.

it should be `my.full.packagename.logexception`

My advice is to keep your "unittests" as simple as possible and give up that idea of getting Aspects to work in your unit test.

Too many mocks is never a good thing,
[Testing on the Toilet: Don’t Overuse Mocks](https://testing.googleblog.com/2013/05/testing-on-toilet-dont-overuse-mocks.html)

Comment: Hi Thomas, 
Thanks for the feedback. My question is, if the aspect itself is not loaded, how does the execution break, when I create a breakpoint at `private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserExceptionLoggingAdvisor.class);` in the Aspect class?